# extract title using ImportXML in google spreadsheets

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I am trying to extract the title of http://help.sketchup.com/en/article/56085 in google spreadsheets using =importxml("http://help.sketchup.com/en/article/56085","//title"). I am getting an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Thx

---

=importxml(Url,"//title/text()") worked on most of the links except the following three....anyideas?

[Example1](http://help.sketchup.com/en/article/56085)
[Example2](http://help.sketchup.com/en/article/141303)
[Example3](http://help.sketchup.com/en/article/36254)

Answer (score 5):

It should be //head/title or to be exact =IMPORTXML("http://help.sketchup.com/en/article/56085", "//head/title")

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

```
//td/@title
```

Answer (score 1):

All 4 of your links worked completely fine in my sheets with this:

```
=importxml("url","//title")
```

This is the same formula you have listed in your questions so I'm not quite sure what the problem is? What kind of an error did you get?